# How to use .exe from VS2013 in UWP app passing AppContainer check?

Tags: c#, uwp, appcontainer

I am new to UWP and I have:

- a game for UWP(Windows 10 only exported from Unity)
- an executable (.exe) file (configuration generator for game, simple winform builded in VS2013 .Net 4.5)

When I call my exe from game it works perfect. Launching by `FullTrustProcessLauncher`:(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.fulltrustprocesslauncher)

But when I upload my game in MS Store. It failed some checking:

> "%PATH_TO_EXE%/*.exe has failed the AppContainerCheck check."

I understand what is it but I am so confused because of reading docs about UWP, AppContainerCheck and etc

I installed VS2019 and import my project but I don't understand what I have to do. I have some variants:

- rebuild project as .appxupload and call it from my export-from-Unity-UWP-game
- rebuild as Desktop Bridge
- do something with /APPCONTAINER (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/appcontainer-windows-store-app?view=vs-2019)
- do something with -target:appcontainerexe (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/target-appcontainerexe-compiler-option)

I understand that my exe-file must be run in an app container but how to rebuild my exe from VS2013 in VS2019 to pass the AppContainerCheck check?

Comment: FullTrustProcessLauncher means you're not running the EXE in the AppContainer at all. Your AppXManifest would need to declare the `runFullTrust` capability in order to successfully do that, in which case the test shouldn't apply. Do you somehow have the EXE named in the manifest as an entry point
?

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT do you mean `<desktop:Extension Category="windows.fullTrustProcess" Executable="MY_APP_NAME.exe">`?

Comment: Your "UWP" process would not have Windows.FullTrustProcess,but the exe you're trying to launch. See [MSDN docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.ApplicationModel.FullTrustProcessLauncher).